# Only increment a value after certain number of frames has passed

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, digital

I recently wrote a program that makes a signal I'm plotting digital. It's pretty straight forward:

```
def plotdigital(Af):
    arraysbinary = []
    blinkcheck = False
    for i in Af:
        if i >  -15 and blinkcheck == False:
            arraysbinary.append(1)
            blinkcheck = True
        else:
            arraysbinary.append(0)
    return arraysbinary
```

Af is the signal I'm working on and i is the current element. So whenever i reaches the value of -15 I append 1 to the arraysbinary. The signal is an eye-tracker and it sometimes counts one blink as two separate ones very close to each other like so: 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
My goal is once I detect an i to not allow the program to detect another i> 15 for about 20 frames after it's detected the first one, thus ensuring that each blink is counted as one and not as two separate ones. I've started working on a solution with a boolean that is supposed to switch to True once an i>15 has been detected, but I can't seem to finish the program off so it switches to False for the next 20 frames (i+20). Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Can you provide some sample for the `Af` input together with an expected `arraysbinary` output?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the index value in if condition for your min consecutive frame threshold. See below:

```
frame_threshold = 2
def plotdigital(Af):
    arraysbinary = []
    last_blink_checkpoint = 0
    for (index, value) in enumerate(Af):
        if value > 5 and last_blink_checkpoint + frame_threshold < index:
            arraysbinary.append(1)
            last_blink_checkpoint = index
        else:
            arraysbinary.append(0)
    return arraysbinary

test = [1,2,23,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,6,9,453,0,45,4,8,5,4,3,4,34,63,46,34]

print(plotdigital(test))
```

Note: I have used a different comparison value than yours, please change it as per your use case.